# Transfer files from local machine(i.e) windows to remote machine(Ubuntu) using ANT script through scp

Tags: ant

I wrote this simple script to transfer files from my machine to remote machine. Here I included the jars of ant.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="File_Transfer_using_ANT" default=".">
   <property name="lib" location="lib" />
   <path id="project.classpath">
      <fileset dir="${lib}">
         <include name="*.jar" />
      </fileset>
   </path>
   <target name="copy">
      <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
      <scp todir="username:password@ip:path/">
         <fileset dir="source path">
            <include name="**/*.txt" />
         </fileset>
      </scp>
   </target>
</project>
```

Error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jcraft.jsch.Session.setConfig(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:221)

I also Added jar file required into ant lib path. I don't know where I did wrong.

Comment: Include the depencies in the classpath.

Comment: I have included jar in the lib folder in ant

Comment: please update your build script in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the update; what is the project structure?

Comment: In project_folder i have these files and folder
---->lib_folder
 ---->build.xml 
---->text_file

Comment: I Successfully completed the code and run it in my windows to copy file to linux machine.No lib folder paths are required in the code.